# static_assert fails while using constinit const. Confusion in constinit, constinit const, constexpr, const, nonconst variables

Tags: c++, constexpr, c++20, constinit

I have a question about compile time functions. I understand that static_assert should work only with types, that can be evaluated/computed at compile time. So it does not work with std::string (yet, no support in gcc10 for constexpr std::string) but will work with std::array(when I know size at compile time). I am watching C++ Weekly from Jason Turner, so this snippet is from this episode https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=INn3xa4pMfg.

The code is here: https://godbolt.org/z/e3WPTP

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename Key, typename Value, std::size_t Size>
struct Map final
{
    std::array<std::pair<Key, Value>, Size> _data;

    [[nodiscard]] constexpr Value getMappedKey(const Key& aKey) const
    {
        const auto mapIterator = std::ranges::find_if(_data, [&aKey](const auto& pair){ return pair.first == aKey;});

        if(mapIterator != _data.end())
        {
            return mapIterator->second;
        }
        else
        {
            throw std::out_of_range("Key is not in the map");
        }
    }
};

enum class OurEnum
{
    OUR_VALUE,
    OUR_VALUE2,
    OUR_VALUE3
};

enum class TheirEnum
{
    THEIR_VALUE,
    THEIR_VALUE2,
    THEIR_VALUE3
};


// This Fails non constant variable of course
/*
    Map<OurEnum, TheirEnum, 2> enumsConverter =
    {
        {
            {{OurEnum::OUR_VALUE, TheirEnum::THEIR_VALUE},
            {OurEnum::OUR_VALUE2, TheirEnum::THEIR_VALUE2}}
        }
    };
*/

// This fails, it is const, but this does not guarentee that it will be created in compile time
/*
    const Map<OurEnum, TheirEnum, 2> enumsConverter =
    {
        {
            {{OurEnum::OUR_VALUE, TheirEnum::THEIR_VALUE},
            {OurEnum::OUR_VALUE2, TheirEnum::THEIR_VALUE2}}
        }
    };
*/

// This works
/*
    constexpr Map<OurEnum, TheirEnum, 2> enumsConverter =
    {
        {
            {{OurEnum::OUR_VALUE, TheirEnum::THEIR_VALUE},
            {OurEnum::OUR_VALUE2, TheirEnum::THEIR_VALUE2}}
        }
    };
*/

//How come this does not work? Oh i see, missing const because constinit does not apply constness
/*
    constinit Map<OurEnum, TheirEnum, 2> enumsConverter =
    {
        {
            {{OurEnum::OUR_VALUE, TheirEnum::THEIR_VALUE},
            {OurEnum::OUR_VALUE2, TheirEnum::THEIR_VALUE2}}
        }
    };
*/

// Okay, I added const specifier but still this makes static_assert fail because of non-constant condition
// Why?

    constinit const Map<OurEnum, TheirEnum, 2> enumsConverter =
    {
        {
            {{OurEnum::OUR_VALUE, TheirEnum::THEIR_VALUE},
            {OurEnum::OUR_VALUE2, TheirEnum::THEIR_VALUE2}}
        }
    };


int main() 
{
    static_assert(enumsConverter.getMappedKey(OurEnum::OUR_VALUE) == TheirEnum::THEIR_VALUE);
}
```

I was playing with this sample and find out, that the static_assert does not work with constinit const initialized map. I commented out every possibility and I would like to explain them.

1. Map is initialized as **non-const** variable. I understand that this will not work, it is not constant variable nor compile time initialized
2. Map is initialized as **const** variable. This will not work either, even though the variable is constant, it is not guaranteed that it will be created at compile time.
3. Map is initialized as **constexpr** variable. This guarantee that the variable will be initialized at compile time. Also it implies constness, so we have compile time const variable. This works correctly. (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)
4. Map is initialized as **constinit** varibale. Now, constinit guarantees, that the expression is zero-intiialized or constant initialized. I initialize with constant so according this variable should be known at compile time (Sets the initial values of the static variables to a compile-time constant. - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_initialization) But it does not implies constness, so we have compile-time non-const variable, this static_assert can not work.
5. Map is initialized as **constinit cons**t variable. Now we have compile-time constant variable but static_assert refuses to work. static_assert needs contextually converted constant expression of type bool (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert)  which is A converted constant expression of type T is an expression implicitly converted to type T, where the converted expression is a constant expression. **Why this does not work?**

According to cppInsights, the generated code by compiler is same as for constinit const and constexpr.

Comment: "chaos" is a bit strong I feel. How about "confusion"? That still keeps the alliteration, if you're into that sort of thing :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to address things from the wrong perspective. You see a variable declared as `constinit const`. You think that, because the object is non-modifiable, and because it is initialized by a constant expression, that this means that the object is a constant expression.

It's not.

Is its value knowable by the compiler? Absolutely. But that's *not* how "constant expression" is defined.

Something is a constant expression because the standard says that it is. A variable declared `constinit` is not a constant expression because the rules don't say that it is. A variable declared `const` is not a constant expression because the rules don't say that it is (except for certain cases of integers, which predate `constexpr`). And there's no special rule for the use of both of these markers.

A variable is a constant expression if it is declared `constexpr` (or one of those `const` integer exceptions). And only constant expressions can appear in `static_assert`.

That's the rule.

And there's no reason to have a special case of using `constinit const` because if you wanted a constant expression... you could have just written `constexpr`. After all, you might be in some template code where someone gave you a `T` that just so happens to be `const`, and you create a `constinit T` variable somewhere. You didn't ask it to be a constant expression; you just wanted a variable that was statically initialized. That the type just so happened to be `const` is just happenstance.

Now sure, the compiler is free to do all kinds of special optimizations with this knowledge. But this isn't about what the compiler is allowed to do; it's about what the language *means*. And if you wanted special meaning from that declaration, you should have said it correctly.

Comment: So constexpr imply constinit then right? Basically these two are same but with one crucial difference. constinit const is not constant expression so it can not be evaluated at compile time, but they are both initialized by constant during compile time.

Comment: @HowP: "*so it can not be evaluated at compile time*" That is not a thing the C++ standard concerns itself with. The C++ standard concerns itself with "constant expressions". Things which are constant expressions can be used in places that require constant expressions, like `static_assert`. Whether something "can be evaluated at compile time" is not what the standard deals with. Compilers have the right to evaluate whatever they want within the limits of the standard. Compiler's don't have the right to use this to allow non-constant expressions to appear where they're not allowed.

Answer (score 7):

> Map is initialized as `constinit const` variable. Now we have compile-time constant variable but `static_assert` refuses to work

The second claim does not follow from the first. We do *not* have a compile-time constant variable, therefore the `static_assert` does not work.

`constinit` does not make your variable a `constexpr` variable, it only guarantees that you have constant initialization (hence the name `constinit`). Indeed, `constinit` does not even imply `const`:

```cpp
constinit std::mutex m;
```

is a valid and motivating use for `constinit`, and still allows me to lock and unlock `m`.

The only way to have a `constexpr` variable is to declare your variable `constexpr` (with an unfortunate legacy carve out for integral types declared `const`, which doesn't apply here). If you want to have a `constexpr` map, you need to declare your map `constexpr`.

Comment: offtopic, but is there a problem with just using std::mutex m (at global scope, assuming it is not used while constructing other statics)?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl No. The only thing `constinit` does is _enforce_ that the initialization performed is constant initialization. It doesn't change _whether_ the initialization is constant initialization. `std::mutex m;` already does constant initialization, `constinit std::mutex m;` would just make it a compile error if it did not.

Answer (score 3):

> Map is initialized as constinit const variable. ... but static_assert refuses to work. ... Why this does not work?

As you have observed, `static_assert` needs the expression to be known at compile time.

However, `const` only implies logical constness, and does not imply that the value is known at compile time (ignoring the case of const integral values initialized with constant expressions).

Similarly, `constinit` only implies static initialization; again, this does not imply that the value is known at compile time.

From the phrasing of your question, I guess you are expecting that:

> `const` + `constinit` --> `constexpr`

But that's not the case. If you want the Map to be usable at compile time (i.e. inside a `static_assert`, you'll need to make it `constexpr`).